# How do I compile this simple "hello world" C++ code on Visual Studio Code? (95% done)

Tags: c++, json, build, visual-studio-code

This is my file. It's called "hello.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello earth" << endl;
}
```

This is something called a json file. It's called "tasks.json"

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "echo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["Hello World"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: Visual studio code is just an editor, it doesn't have a compiler included. Do you have one?

Comment: @Colin__s I think I may have MinGW. But I'm not sure. What compiler would you recommend?

Comment: On Windows i use Visual Studio. If you have MinGW installed, you should have a c++ compiler called `g++`. Try replacing the `"command": "echo",` line with `"command": "g++",` and the `"args": ["Hello World"],` line with `"args": ["hello.cpp"],`

Comment: @Colin__s It actually did not work, but that's okay. So if I download Visual Studio, will this code automatically run here on Visual Studio Code?